# Angular js is not displaying data in edit?

Tags: angularjs

My problem is that data is not show in Edit mode after page refresh before page refresh it display data but after page refresh modelpopup is blank.

My javascript code for edit functionality:

```
$scope.editBook = function (book) {
    var getBookData = crudAJService.getBook(book.Id);
    getBookData.then(function (_book) {

        $scope.book = _book.data;
        $scope.modal.content.bookId = book.Id;
        $scope.modal.content.bookTitle = book.Title;

        $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;  //to display  popup
    }
}
```

My html view code is

```
<tr ng-repeat="book in books">
    <td>{{book.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{book.Title}}</td>                           
    <td>
        <span ng-click="editBook(book)">
            Edit
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.editBook = function (book) {
            var getBookData = crudAJService.getBook(book.Id);
            getBookData.then(function (_book) {

                $scope.modal.content = book;//You have to initialize modal.content
                $scope.book = _book.data;
                $scope.modal.content.bookId = book.Id;
                $scope.modal.content.bookTitle = book.Title;

                $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;  //to display  popup
            }
        }
```

Comment: great answer solution